# Why is my program running slower on a server than locally?

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, performance, solaris

I have a java program that reads data from a database, processes the data and writes it to csv files. The written data can be quite big (2 files are ~600 MB, the total is usually around 1.5 GB, divided in 16 files).

When I run the program with eclipse (Windows 7), it takes around 1 hour.

When I deploy the program on our server, it takes 3.5 hours.

In both cases, the database used is the same.

Does it mean I can rule out the database being the source of the problem ?

If so, what could cause that increase in time execution ?

JVM parameters in eclipse : Java 7, -Xms1200m, I have 4 GB RAM

JVM parameters in solaris : Java 6, -Xms2048M -Xmx3072M, I have 256 GB RAM, with usually 60 GB free.

**Answers to comments :**

@Jordi Castilla : Well, I've run the top command a few times, and the free memory was always at least 60 GB. But I don't know for sure.

@Pradeep Sekar, @dasblinkenlight : how do I check that ?

@jwenting : no SSD, just plain old HDD

@RealSkeptic : what do you mean ? On the same server as the one I am running the program ?

@Drazan Bozanovic : not yet, because it proves difficult and lengthy to install plugins, softwares, tools, that are not standard in my company (and profiling tools have not yet been approved)

@Andrew Henle :

```
r/s     w/s     kr/s    kw/s    wait    actv    wsvc_t  asvc_t  %w  %b  device
1.6     6.5     47.9    207.6   0.0     0.0     0.8     2.5     0   1   risuatfs01-nfs:/RISUATAP01/ACF
```

Comment: *I have 256 GB RAM , with usually 60 GB free.* is that true?

Comment: This could be potentially due to the connection time between server and DB. Your local computer may have better connection time for DB connection than the server.

Comment: Server could go through a different network path to access DB, in which case latency could kill your performance. It could also have its network capacity maxed out, in which case bandwidth would kill your performance.

Comment: and are you using SSDs locally and hard drives on the server? Another big difference in performance.

Comment: Is the database running on the same server?

Comment: Did you try profiling?

Comment: What is the exact hardware for your local development box that is fast, and the server where things are slow?  Also, post the output from `iostat -sndxz 10 3` (run on the Solaris server) while your process is running - given the size of your output file, this could be an IO-bound process, and if so that `iostat` command stands a good chance of showing that.

Comment: The first row of output from `iostat` is useless.

Comment: Is the DB (firewall, network) or I/O (SSD) the problem? Try to find out with a simple test: Change the Java code and check the IO by writing 500 Mb fixed random data to 16 csv files.

Comment: Why are you using an insanely old Java on the server side?